# Failed to export application Command-line Error -1073741819 after updating Eclipse to 23.0.5 and SDK to 5.0

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have updated my Eclipse ADT and I have also updated the SDK to 5.0. I am trying to export unsigned APK file but unfortunately it is encountering an error. You can see in screen shot:

[image]

I have tried all these solutions:

1. deleted the files in bin folder then cleaned project and tried to export again
2. restarted the PC then tried again

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Issue 
go to project Properties>Android Lint Preference>Type "Lint" in the TextField>Select the "LocalSuppress">press Ignore All and press ok .

Now you can Export APK